# Call codebehind function from javascript with parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I need call codebehind function with parameter which is instance of some Entity class from script tags in aspx page. Im created popup windows from kendo ui using kendotemplate and in this template i need my form with inputs and button used in code behind. Something like this http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command but when i add asp items to template tags not work for me.

My entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

code behind function:

```
protected void btnAddPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p= new Person();
        // get values from three inputs
        p.FirstName= personFirstName.Value;
        p.LastName= personLastName.Value;
        p.Age = Convert.ToInt32(personAge.Value);
        ...
    }
```

i need in javascript something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
            <Asp:Input ...>
    <Asp:Input ...>
    <Asp:Input ...>
    <Asp:Button ...>
</script>
```

and sorry for my english